# How to search for Specific Date using Multiple Criteria in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've to search for a specific date using multiple criteria.

**Criteria 1:** UserID (For Example 177)

```
=IF(MATCH(A5,Table_CHECKINOUT4[USERID],0),"Yes")
```

**Criteria 2:** CheckType (For Example I)

```
=IF(MATCH(G4,Table_CHECKINOUT4[CHECKTYPE],0),"Yes")
```

**Criteria 3:** Date (For Example 1/21/2020)

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Table_CHECKINOUT4[CHECKTIME],">="&INT($G$3),Table_CHECKINOUT4[CHECKTIME],"<"&INT($G$3)+1),"Yes","No")
```

I've to search for a specific date in CHECKINOUT sheet using the above three criteria, as shown in the image below:

[image: Data Sheet]

And display the TIME in column cell, as shown in the image below

[image: Excel Sheet]

```
USERID  CHECKTIME   CHECKTYPE
177   1/10/2020 9:37    I
177   1/17/2020 9:25    I
177   1/2/2020 9:14     I
177   1/3/2020 16:37    O
177   1/7/2020 9:26     I
177   1/14/2020 9:09    I
177   1/17/2020 17:10   O
177   1/9/2020 9:15     I
177   1/20/2020 17:32   O
177   1/16/2020 11:01   I
177   1/9/2020 17:39    O
177   1/2/2020 17:08    O
177   1/6/2020 16:34    I
177   1/13/2020 9:15    I
177   1/16/2020 17:09   O
177   1/21/2020 9:06    I
177   1/8/2020 16:59    I
177   1/20/2020 17:29   O
177   1/15/2020 9:15    I
177   1/20/2020 9:14    I
177   1/10/2020 15:00   I
177   1/1/2020 16:58    O
177   1/3/2020 9:09     I
177   1/7/2020 17:39    O
177   1/21/2020 16:57   O
177   1/8/2020 9:19     I
177   1/15/2020 17:10   O
177   1/14/2020 16:49   I
```

Comment: I tried I do not have time to retype your table to test.  If you would post the data as text I may have time to fix my attempt.

Comment: Posted the table data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMIFS:

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/MOD(SUMIFS(Table_CHECKINOUT4[CHECKTIME],Table_CHECKINOUT4[CHECKTIME],">="&INT($G$3),Table_CHECKINOUT4[CHECKTIME],"<"&INT($G$3)+1,Table_CHECKINOUT4[USERID],$A4,Table_CHECKINOUT4[CHECKTYPE],$G$4),1)),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As option - SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Table_CHECKINOUT4[USERID]=F2)*(INT(Table_CHECKINOUT4[CHECKTIME])=$K$2)*(Table_CHECKINOUT4[CHECKTYPE]=$L$2)*MOD(Table_CHECKINOUT4[CHECKTIME],1))
```

[image]